# Query JSON Data using SQL Server OpenJson - ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure what's wrong with this below SQL query. I am getting below error message

> 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.'

Can anyone please help me to fix this query

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{ 

    "pets" : {
            "cats" : [
            { "id" : 1, "name" : "Fluffy", "gender" : "Female" },
            { "id" : 2, "name" : "Long Tail", "gender" : "Female" },
            { "id" : 3, "name" : "Scratch", "gender" : "Male" }
        ],
            "dogs" : [
            { "name" : "Fetch", "gender" : "Male" },
            { "name" : "Fluffy", "gender" : "Male" },
            { "name" : "Wag", "gender" : "Female" }
        ]
    }
}'

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.pets.cats')
WITH(

        [Cat Id]    int,  
        [Cat Name]  varchar(60), 
        [Gender]    varchar(6), 
        [Cats]      nvarchar(max)
    );
```

P.S. I am using SQL server 2017 14.0

Comment: The statement is correct, but doesn't return any results, because you need to define the `path` in the explicit schema (the `WITH` clause). About the error - check the compatibility error of your database.

Comment: are you not getting any syntax error? @Zhorov

Comment: You might be using SQL Server 2017 but sounds like your database is in a compatibility level of 120 or lower. That's the only time I  can repro the error. The above works fine in a compatibility level of 130 or higher.

Comment: If you run `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'YourDbNameHere'`, what number do you get in the output?

Comment: @Naren, yes, the same error, when I test the statement with SQL Server 2014. Change the compatibility level of your database.

Comment: @DavidG  - compatibility_level is 120

Comment: Well that's my crystal ball usage for the month... It's now flashing red and says "You cannot use this crystal ball for another 40,314 minutes." :(

Comment: If you want to use `OPENJSON` @Naren, your database must be at least level 130. This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (note the big notes box at the start of the document).

Comment: When I go to my DB properties, under options I see compatibility_level showing SQL Server 2014(120).

Comment: It even tells you in the docs at the top of the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Larnu - Yes, compatibility level 130 or higher needed :(

Comment: So the question is, @Naren, why isn't your database in 130+? SQL Server 2017 uses level 140; have you recently migrated to 2017 and so haven't changed the level yet? (though i would be surprised if you've recently migrated, as 2017 is nearing end of mainstream support). If you haven't recently upgraded, why are you still at level 120? Is there a breaking change that you're trying to avoid (such as the behaviour the the date and time data types)?